# How to initialize items in an ItemGroup with default values?

Tags: msbuild

A property can be initialized to a default value in a `PropertyGroup` like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyProperty Condition="$(MyProperty) == ''">MyDefaultValue</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with Items?:

```
<ItempGroup>
    <MyItems Condition="MyItems is no defined" Include="MyDefaultFile.ext;"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Currently I'm doing:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyItems Condition="!Exists(@(MyItems))" Include="MyDefaultFile.ext;"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I don't think this is good idea (i.e The files in `MyItems` may not exist, while `MyItems` may be defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the condition on the `ItemGroup` level:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'@(MyItems)' == ''">
  <MyItems Include="MyDefaultFile.ext" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can also use [`ItemDefinitionGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629392.aspx) to initialize default metadata values.

Comment: Just clarifying for other readers. The "Include" keyword means to append another item to the item list called "MyItems".